# What should return text.FirstOrDefault(q => true) and what is difference between text.FirstOrDefault(q => true) and text.FirstOrDefault()?

Tags: c#, .net

`What is difference  between text.FirstOrDefault(q => true) and text.FirstOrDefault()?`

The both returns the same result, so in which case brackets with expression can be needed ?

Comment: The latter is clearer. There is no good reason to use the first form. The first form says 'give me the first entry that meets this condition' (and the condition is always true). So, in practice the first form is just a more verbose (and slightly confusing) form of the second form. The second form is also likely to play better with `IQueryable` etc etc.

Comment: They are radicly different. One selects the first element based on a condition (or default if none found). The other simply returns the first element of a enumerable (or default if none found).

Comment: The problem is far more interesting if you compare `Single` rather than `FirstOrDefault` since the different implementations of that (on .NET Framework, not Core) do *actually* act markedly differently. https://dotnetfiddle.net/sZZsDM

Comment: Thats very interesting @mjwills. `Single` with a conditional throws an exception if 2 elements that match that condition exist. Without a condtional  it throws whenever 2 or more elements exist in the collection (4.7.2 docs). Logicaly, `Single`with a conditional checks for duplicates in the whole collection and without a conditional has enough info looking at the first 2 elements, hence the exception is not hit in this example without a conditional. Changing the order of elements (exception in position 2) does hit the exeption in both instances. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Woah where to start.

[Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netcore-3.1)

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no
>   element is found.

[FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable, Func)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_FirstOrDefault__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__)

> Returns the first element of the sequence that satisfies a condition
>   or a default value if no such element is found.

In the `FirstOrDefault(q => true)` example you give `true`, so you are saying, give me the first or default element of an array of char, where "true = true"

¯_(ツ)_/¯

They are, for all intents and purposes the same. Well, except for the fact the first variation is a verbose and inefficient way of doing nothing more than the other

Answer (score 0):

As far as i'm aware, there is no difference between `text.FirstOrDefault(q => true)` and `text.FirstOrDefault()`, and the `q => true` is essentially the same as writing `if(true){}`

There are however, many ways you can use the `FirstOrDefault` method.

```
text.FirstOrDefault(x => x == "abc")
text.FirstOrDefault(x => x == 123)
text.FirstOrDefault(x => !list.Contains(x))
text.FirstOrDefault(x => x != y)
```